# SOA and Oracle cascade data between two pdb

Tags: oracle, database-design, java, application-design

I am Java developer and need help for design and manage database .
Please view this picture :
[image: SOA & Database Design]

I have two service named :
**1)** Authentication Service (Register new user and login)
**2)** Customer service (Record User Information like address,phone,....)

**my question is :**
what happened in customer database if authentication service remove a user from database ?
How can manage dirty data from customer pdb ?

Note 1 : two services have not any access to other Oracle pdbs .
Note 2 : customer is child of authentication (Father) so authentication service can not connect to child web services (Only customer can connect to authentication service)

**Update :** This is only a simple example for describe what i want to do .

Answer (score 0):

## INTRO

If you use different database accounts for "Authentication Service" and "Customer Service", you can easily control what each REST Service can see and do.

This is what database are designed to do: Control of access to data.

By levering the database's ability to secure access to data, you can use a single `USER_INFO` table in a single database.

## Conceptual Setup

Your `USER_INFO` table should be treated as (java parlance) `private`.

Since `USER_INFO` is `private`, you do not `GRANT` access on that table to the accounts used by the REST services.

You use `VIEWS` and `PACKAGES` as your (java parlance) `public` interface to that `private` data.

The account for "Authentication Service" will get access to one set of `VIEWS` and `PACKAGES`.
The account for "Customer Service" will get access to another set of `VIEWS` and `PACKAGES`.

A `VIEW` can easily limit what columns are displayed.  In some cases, you can control what Rows can be displayed.

A `PACKAGES` is just a collection of function/procedures.
eg `registerUser` and `loginNamePassword` would belong to `PACKAGE AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_API`

You could, almost, think of a `PACKAGE` as a (java parlance) `class`.

Your design would look like this:
[image]

## ANSWERS

1. You are now using a single table.  This isn't a concern
2. You are now using a single table.  Oracle doesn't do `dirty data`(*).

(*) I'm ignoring the DBMS package for 2-phase commits that allows you to do that.

Comment: Thank you mean . but with this design I have a another problem . I use JPA (Hibernate ORM) and use two entity class named User and Customer . hbm2ddl create separate tables for each entities .

Comment: Within SOA Design, the database is quite capable of acting as a Service Provider on its own.  If you expose the `VIEWS` and `Procedures` as REST calls via `Oracle RESTful Data Service [ORDS]`, your hibernate code becomes unnecessary.  Additionally, no experienced database developer will expose passwords to applications. Your java code is incapable of validating name/password.  You have no choice but to call the DB procedure `validateNamePassword` (I don't think Hibernate can help you their)